# Unable to read Project file "xyz.vcxproj" in Visual Studio 2015. Root Element is missing

Tags: image-processing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda

Error message:

[image]

While opening a cuda sample downloaded from NVIDIA site the given error popped up. Can you please help to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in Project property file. 
The "Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user"file(located in AppData->Local->Microsoft->MSBuild->v.4.0) was found to be empty .
Enter code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
       <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
       </ImportGroup>
       <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
       <PropertyGroup />
       <ItemDefinitionGroup />
       <ItemGroup />
 </Project>
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Small disclaimer: I'm still on VS2013 but I assume that VS still use an xml-format for the project files.

You can try to open the vcxproj-file in a text editor and check for missing tags. An error could have occurred that removed a tag or end-tag. It can help to compare against a working project file. If you do not have one, just create one from within VS2015.

From the error message I am guessing that some top-level tag is missing. Either that or some tag that is missing enclosing upper-level tags introduced in VS2015  and that the file is not properly upgraded from an earlier version.

Comment: Thank you for the reply . I have started using Cuda and this is  the first project . I don't have a working cuda file  thus can't compare .

Comment: Not a working cuda file, a working Visual Studio project file. Just start a new project in Visual Studio (File->New->Project and select a template) to get a working vcxproj-file. But it seems you already solved the problem?